# Convert Lab color to RGB

Tags: ios, colors

I am trying to convert a Lab color into RGB. As an example for this conversion, Photoshop 
converts

```
L= 100, a = 0, b = 127
```

into

```
R=255, G=252, B=0.
```

This color is bright yellow.

I have written the following conversion routine (C/Objective C). However, something 
is not right. The code will output

```
XYZ = 100.000000 100.000000 4.862713
RGB = 163.908401 90.755638 -13.093634
```

Here the mismatch between the the RGB-result and Photoshop's RGB seems to be quite large.
The negative blue component is also a problem.

Any ideas on how to correct the below code would be greatly appreciated? Or, any other algorithms/formulas/pseudocode for converting Lab into RGB? Thank you.

The code:

```
/*
 *   See Wikipedia artice on Lab color space
 *
 *    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space
 *
 */
CGFloat fInv (CGFloat t) {

   CGFloat T0 = (CGFloat) 6.0f/29.0f;

   if (t > T0) {
       return t*t*t;
   }

   return 3.0 * T0 * T0 * (t - 4.0f/29.0f);

}


int test() {

    //
    //  Bright yellow test 
    //
    CGFloat Ls = 100.0f;
    CGFloat as = 0.0f;
    CGFloat bs = 127.0f;

    //
    //  Reference white point (ad hoc)
    //
    CGFloat Xn = 100;
    CGFloat Yn = 100;    
    CGFloat Zn = 100;

    //
    //   Taken Wikipedia (see above)
    //
    CGFloat X =  Xn * fInv(1/116.0f * (Ls + 16.0f) + 1/500.0f * as);
    CGFloat Y =  Yn * fInv(1/116.0f * (Ls + 16.0f));
    CGFloat Z =  Zn * fInv(1/116.0f * (Ls + 16.0f) - 1/200.0f * bs);

    NSLog(@" XYZ = %f %f %f", X, Y, Z);

    // 
    // 
    //   XYZ to RGB transfomration using AppleRGB. Taken from 
    //
    //       http://brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html
    //
    //
    CGFloat r =  2.9515373 * X  - 1.2894116 * Y - 0.4738445 * Z;
    CGFloat g = -1.0851093 * X  + 1.9908566 * Y + 0.0372026 * Z;
    CGFloat b =  0.0854934 * X  - 0.2694964 * Y + 1.0912975 * Z;

    NSLog(@" RGB = %f %f %f", r, g, b);

 }
```

Comment: It is in fact very difficult to convert RGB to LAB satisfactory. I elaborated a bit more on it in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976069/why-do-i-not-find-a-lab-color-cube) if you're interested.

Comment: I am trying to achieve same thing. @user467225 any success?

Answer (score 13):

Try implementing formulas from [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20111111073514/http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=08#text8). I just implemented RGB->Lab(through XYZ) and it works fine.

C++ code:

```
// using https://web.archive.org/web/20111111080001/http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=01#tex1
void rgb2lab( float R, float G, float B, float & l_s, float &a_s, float &b_s )
{
    float var_R = R/255.0;
    float var_G = G/255.0;
    float var_B = B/255.0;


    if ( var_R > 0.04045 ) var_R = pow( (( var_R + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ), 2.4 );
    else                   var_R = var_R / 12.92;
    if ( var_G > 0.04045 ) var_G = pow( ( ( var_G + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ), 2.4);
    else                   var_G = var_G / 12.92;
    if ( var_B > 0.04045 ) var_B = pow( ( ( var_B + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ), 2.4);
    else                   var_B = var_B / 12.92;

    var_R = var_R * 100.;
    var_G = var_G * 100.;
    var_B = var_B * 100.;

    //Observer. = 2°, Illuminant = D65
    float X = var_R * 0.4124 + var_G * 0.3576 + var_B * 0.1805;
    float Y = var_R * 0.2126 + var_G * 0.7152 + var_B * 0.0722;
    float Z = var_R * 0.0193 + var_G * 0.1192 + var_B * 0.9505;


    float var_X = X / 95.047 ;         //ref_X =  95.047   Observer= 2°, Illuminant= D65
    float var_Y = Y / 100.000;          //ref_Y = 100.000
    float var_Z = Z / 108.883;          //ref_Z = 108.883

    if ( var_X > 0.008856 ) var_X = pow(var_X , ( 1./3. ) );
    else                    var_X = ( 7.787 * var_X ) + ( 16. / 116. );
    if ( var_Y > 0.008856 ) var_Y = pow(var_Y , ( 1./3. ));
    else                    var_Y = ( 7.787 * var_Y ) + ( 16. / 116. );
    if ( var_Z > 0.008856 ) var_Z = pow(var_Z , ( 1./3. ));
    else                    var_Z = ( 7.787 * var_Z ) + ( 16. / 116. );

    l_s = ( 116. * var_Y ) - 16.;
    a_s = 500. * ( var_X - var_Y );
    b_s = 200. * ( var_Y - var_Z );


}

// https://web.archive.org/web/20111111080001/http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=01#tex1
void lab2rgb( float l_s, float a_s, float b_s, float& R, float& G, float& B )
{
    float var_Y = ( l_s + 16. ) / 116.;
    float var_X = a_s / 500. + var_Y;
    float var_Z = var_Y - b_s / 200.;

    if ( pow(var_Y,3) > 0.008856 ) var_Y = pow(var_Y,3);
    else                      var_Y = ( var_Y - 16. / 116. ) / 7.787;
    if ( pow(var_X,3) > 0.008856 ) var_X = pow(var_X,3);
    else                      var_X = ( var_X - 16. / 116. ) / 7.787;
    if ( pow(var_Z,3) > 0.008856 ) var_Z = pow(var_Z,3);
    else                      var_Z = ( var_Z - 16. / 116. ) / 7.787;

    float X = 95.047 * var_X ;    //ref_X =  95.047     Observer= 2°, Illuminant= D65
    float Y = 100.000 * var_Y  ;   //ref_Y = 100.000
    float Z = 108.883 * var_Z ;    //ref_Z = 108.883


    var_X = X / 100. ;       //X from 0 to  95.047      (Observer = 2°, Illuminant = D65)
    var_Y = Y / 100. ;       //Y from 0 to 100.000
    var_Z = Z / 100. ;      //Z from 0 to 108.883

    float var_R = var_X *  3.2406 + var_Y * -1.5372 + var_Z * -0.4986;
    float var_G = var_X * -0.9689 + var_Y *  1.8758 + var_Z *  0.0415;
    float var_B = var_X *  0.0557 + var_Y * -0.2040 + var_Z *  1.0570;

    if ( var_R > 0.0031308 ) var_R = 1.055 * pow(var_R , ( 1 / 2.4 ))  - 0.055;
    else                     var_R = 12.92 * var_R;
    if ( var_G > 0.0031308 ) var_G = 1.055 * pow(var_G , ( 1 / 2.4 ) )  - 0.055;
    else                     var_G = 12.92 * var_G;
    if ( var_B > 0.0031308 ) var_B = 1.055 * pow( var_B , ( 1 / 2.4 ) ) - 0.055;
    else                     var_B = 12.92 * var_B;

    R = var_R * 255.;
    G = var_G * 255.;
    B = var_B * 255.;

}
```

Comment: They won't match Photoshop as well.

Comment: I don't believe the floats here are accurate enough. If you convert from rgb to lab and back it isn't the same number. On top of that if you do the conversion several times a channel can potentialy be below 0.

Comment: The lab2rgb function doesn't seems to work for D50 illuminant? I replaced the XYZ values to (96.422, 100.000, 82.521) from the reference values but the conversion is way off. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
void LAB2RGB(int L, int a, int b, unsigned char & R, unsigned char & G, unsigned char & B)
{
    float X, Y, Z, fX, fY, fZ;
    int RR, GG, BB;

    fY = pow((L + 16.0) / 116.0, 3.0);
    if (fY < 0.008856)
        fY = L / 903.3;
    Y = fY;

    if (fY > 0.008856)
        fY = powf(fY, 1.0/3.0);
    else
        fY = 7.787 * fY + 16.0/116.0;

    fX = a / 500.0 + fY;      
    if (fX > 0.206893)
        X = powf(fX, 3.0);
    else
        X = (fX - 16.0/116.0) / 7.787;

    fZ = fY - b /200.0;      
    if (fZ > 0.206893)
        Z = powf(fZ, 3.0);
    else
        Z = (fZ - 16.0/116.0) / 7.787;

    X *= (0.950456 * 255);
    Y *=             255;
    Z *= (1.088754 * 255);

    RR =  (int)(3.240479*X - 1.537150*Y - 0.498535*Z + 0.5);
    GG = (int)(-0.969256*X + 1.875992*Y + 0.041556*Z + 0.5);
    BB =  (int)(0.055648*X - 0.204043*Y + 1.057311*Z + 0.5);

    R = (unsigned char)(RR < 0 ? 0 : RR > 255 ? 255 : RR);
    G = (unsigned char)(GG < 0 ? 0 : GG > 255 ? 255 : GG);
    B = (unsigned char)(BB < 0 ? 0 : BB > 255 ? 255 : BB);

    //printf("Lab=(%f,%f,%f) ==> RGB(%f,%f,%f)\n",L,a,b,*R,*G,*B);
}
```

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Please refer to http://ai.stanford.edu/~ruzon/software/rgblab.html.

Comment: @herohuyongtao thanks! unfortunately that code has pretty bad documentation like “Alter fY slightly for further calculations”. [this page](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Equations.html) has the math!

Comment: Answering myself... the reference white is D65 and is in the lines with 0.950456, nothing (= 1) and 1.088754. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminant_D65

Comment: This reference won't match Photoshop's LAB conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Each i-device is slightly different colour-wise, but I believe Apple recommends sRGB as the device colour space for all devices. Certainly for iPad 3/4, the display matches sRGB. (See [this colour analysis](http://cdtobie.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/color-analysis-of-the-ipad-mini/))

What this means is, if you're after accurate colours, you should use an sRGB ICC profile to help you convert your Lab colour values. You can use the open source software [Little CMS](http://www.littlecms.com/index.html) to do this conversion for you.