# why do I not find a LAB color cube?

Tags: r, colors

I use the R `colorspace` package to convert a three-dimensional point into a LAB color. The LAB color is defined with three coordinates, the first one ranges from 0 to 100 and the two other ones range from -100 to 100.

But searching with Google I do not find a cuboidal representation of the LAB color space. Why ?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If not, StackOverflow isn't the place to ask.

Comment: No it's not directly a programming question but it is somewhat related. And I have already seen some StackOverflow members talking about color spaces... otherwise do you know an appropriate place to ask such a question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

The LAB color space, a.k.a. gamut, contain colors that are impossible to reproduce in nature or on a screen (according to [this page](http://photo.net/learn/digital-photography-workflow/advanced-photoshop-tutorials/using-lab-color-adjustments/)).

#### Elaboration on converting RGB to LAB

I guess the reason you ask is that you want to make some kind of printed material and want to be sure the colors turn out right. I am merely an enthusiastic amateur in this field, but think this paragraph from the [wikipedia article on lab color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space#RGB_and_CMYK_conversions) explains some of the complications.

> There are no simple formulas for conversion between RGB or CMYK values
>   and L*a*b*, because the RGB and CMYK color models are device
>   dependent. The RGB or CMYK values first need to be transformed to a
>   specific absolute color space, such as sRGB or Adobe RGB. This
>   adjustment will be device dependent, but the resulting data from the
>   transform will be device independent, allowing data to be transformed
>   to the CIE 1931 color space and then transformed into L*a*b*.

That is, in order to create a lab color cube, you must first find the transformation from your monitor specific color space into absolute color space. This is surprisingly difficult since the mapping is not linear or on any other simple form. The transformation is not likely to be perfect either since the RGB and LAB spaces do not span the same subspace (speculating here). I once talked to a printmaker about this and he said altough the human eye only has 4 types of color receptors (RGB + light intensity) you need about 17 color components on generate the full spectrum of visible colors on paper. Both RGB and LAB compromises on that, optimized for different purposes.

#### Bottom line

You can calibrate your screen to set up the transformation needed to convert the RGB of the screen to the LAB colors of human eyes, and then go on to make a color cube. However, it will only apply to your very monitor and not be perfect. You are best off test printing different color profiles and choose the one you like best.

Comment: Another time I encountered this problem is when I wanted to make a plot with *many* colors. I tried to find an algorithm that would give me a set of `n` colors maximally different from each other perceptually, realized I couldn't use RGB space and the whole matter turned insanely complicated. Evenually I just gave up.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I'm not really interested in getting the right colors: the important point is to well perceive the differences between colors. I have a series of three-dimensional points and I linearly transform their coordinates to fit with the range of the colorspace R package. Do you think it is a good practice ?

Comment: Yes that sounds like a good idea, and the package seems very nice. Didn't know of it before so thanks for the tip. I use [color brewer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) for choosing colors, as they have carefully selected their palettes to be easy to discerne (and look good).

Comment: Dear Backlin, I think it would be interesting to make the following test: we consider three points O, A, B, in the cuboidal LAB space of the colorspace R package, we code these points with the corresponding color and we ask to people whether they think that color A or color B is furthest to color O. Can we really expect that most of the people will choose the point which is furthest from O for the Euclidean distance ?

Comment: That would be interesting. I guess people should be able to get it fairly right, or at least better than in RGB space (where all green and yellow shades look more or less the same above certain values).

Comment: The "short answer" gives the main point, although it confuses colour space: a geometric representation of colour in space, and colour gamut: a volume in a colour space consisting of all those colours that can be created (CIE definitions). LAB is a theoretical colour space, in which you can draw *any* gamut – but *none* is cubic.

Comment: The "elaboration" is obscure to me. The problem is not converting RGB to LAB, but the reverse. To make a "cuboidal" representation of LAB, first define a cube in the L*, a*, b* coordinates – trivial, since they are Cartesian. Then use the formulae to convert the L*,a*,b* values into R,G,B values in the target RGB space of your choice – tricky, because there will be colours that can't be represented (they're out gamut), but this is the way it is. Finally, colour management will (hopefully) take care of rendering the image as you intended on your particular display.

Comment: It is difficult to make sense of the (speculative) statement that "the RGB and LAB spaces do not span the same subspace". First, you have to specify the RGB space you are working in (like sRGB or Adobe RGB quoted above). Anyway, in what space would LAB "span" a "subspace"? LAB is the reference space for colour management (together with XYZ), inside which RGB spaces span some (usually small) volume, (almost always) smaller than the full human gamut.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how "both RGB and LAB compromises" on generating visible colours on paper, since none is concerned with this. RGB models the generation of colours on electronic systems, while CMY(K) models colour printing. CIE LAB models human perception, and contains all of the colours you can possibly get on screen or on paper (and much more: as a mathematical model, it includes unphysical colours).

Comment: As for the "bottom line", I don't see how it answers the question. If the poster has not seen a "cuboidal representation of the LAB color space", it's not because of monitors' technical limitations, it's because LAB contains more than what he can see (as correctly said in the first line of the answer). Conversely, if you ever see some colourful cube or square said to be LAB, you can immediately tell that this is faked, and can't be a faithful representation of the space.

Comment: The statement you give in your short answer appears to contradict what [Bruce Lindbloom](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/WorkingSpaceInfo.html) has to say about the LAB gamut.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no such thing. The CIELAB colour space has a Cartesian representation (of infinite size), but the (finite) gamut that we can perceive is not cubic, it has a complicated shape. Varying the two coordinates a* and b* independently in a pre-defined range may seem convenient, but this is fundamentally not the way human perception works.

Comment: how does this add to the existing answer ... ?

Comment: The point was not so much to add, but rather to remove the convolution in the only preceding answer. I have now made explicit my main concerns in the comments, and tried to clarify some confused parts.